# Simple client identification in WCF

Tags: .net, wcf

I'm using a self-hosted WCF service with duplex tcp binding without any kind of security. I'd like to transport a username and password from the client so the server code can check for validity. How do I do that? The main goal is to keep it simple.

My idea was to set the binding.ClientCredentials property when establishing the connection, but I don't see how I can access these properties in the server code.

Comment: Do you want to use custom validation or do you want to use Windows accounts? Is the client in the same windows domain as the server?

Comment: Custom validation, no Windows accounts or domains.